# https request with nsurlconnection is time out in ios

Tags: ios, ssl, https, request

I try to request with HTTPS but it not worked ios 8 and ios 9 for this problem I chanced the info.plis like below. But i still get error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."  _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domainname.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

How can I solve this problem ? Could you help me?